# Include Documentation badges in "Select your next badge" window

Tags: feature-request, documentation, badges, badge-progress

The new documentation badges does not appear on the  "Select your next badge" window.

- Documentation Beta
- Documentation Pioneer
- Knowledgeable

See attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why would we add a tracker for the Beta badge when it is no longer obtainable because the private beta is over? Similarly for the Pioneer badge, it is only obtainable for a month, then the code would be useless because you can't earn it anymore. Those two will never be added to the tracker.

Comment: OK, That makes sense

Comment: @animuson if pioneer and beta are no longer obtainable would think we should mark them (retired).