# All documentation badges missing from next badge picker

Tags: feature-request, documentation, badges, badge-progress

**Note**: [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329045/include-documentation-badges-in-select-your-next-badge-window) is similar, but only covers the documentation beta/pioneer badges. I can understand why they aren't included in this picker.

I'm interested to know why none of the documentation badges can be tracked or even seen in the "Select your next badge" window on the profile page?

Both badges that have already been awarded and those that have not are missing. My understanding is that the profile should include these badges as documentation reputation and badges are integrated (and displayed in the "Badges" section) with this profile.

This was reported by me during the private Documentation Beta, but no response was ever received.

[image: The badge picker, missing documentation badges]
[image: My actual badges, including documentation badges]

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is really new, so I don't mind if none of its badges can be tracked yet. None of them really have "progress" anyway.

And besides, there's already a Documentation badge that can be tracked: Educated. =P but you've probably already earned that one.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought it was strange they're missing. Didn't realise Educated was added.

Comment: Why was Educated added and the others not though? It's either done or not done too...

Comment: @pgmann probably because it's to encourage reading it, just like Informed.